# Selecting/sorting values withing table R

Tags: r

I'm working in **R** with the following dataset for a metabolomics study.

```
first Name      Area    Sample Similarity

120   Pentanone 699468  PO4:1   954

120   Pentanone 153744  PO2:1   981

126   Methylamine 83528 PO4:1   887

126   Unknown     32741 PO2:1   645

126   Sulfurous 43634   PO1:1   800
```

I want to be able to selected in the first column, within the rowns with same value (for example 120), the compounds with same name (for example pentanone). From this selection I want to copy the row information that corresponds to the highest similarity and created new columns within the table. In this case the following information:

```
120 Pentanone   153744  PO2:1   981
```

I know that "send me the code posts" are not very appreciated by I would greatly appreciated some clues on how to start.

Comment: What have you tried so far (include some code in your question) and what was the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many options. You already have one example using `plyr`; here are two more.

Base R approach, using `aggregate` and `merge`:

```
merge(dat, aggregate(Similarity ~ first + Name, dat, max))
#   first        Name Similarity   Area Sample
# 1   120   Pentanone        981 153744  PO2:1
# 2   126 Methylamine        887  83528  PO4:1
# 3   126   Sulfurous        800  43634  PO1:1
# 4   126     Unknown        645  32741  PO2:1
```

A `sqldf` approach:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select *, max(Similarity) `Similarity` from dat group by first, Name")
#   first        Name Similarity   Area Sample
# 1   120   Pentanone        981 153744  PO2:1
# 2   126 Methylamine        887  83528  PO4:1
# 3   126   Sulfurous        800  43634  PO1:1
# 4   126     Unknown        645  32741  PO2:1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use plyr package:

I reproduce your data ( try to use dput(dat) next time)

```
dat <- read.table(text ='first Name      Area    Sample Similarity
120   Pentanone 699468  PO4:1   954
120   Pentanone 153744  PO2:1   981
126   Methylamine 83528 PO4:1   887
126   Unknown     32741 PO2:1   645
126   Sulfurous 43634   PO1:1   800',header=TRUE)
```

1. I split my data.frame by (first & Name)
2. I apply the function fo each set of rows
3. I aggregate in a new data.frame

   ```
   library(plyr)   
   ddply(dat,.(first,Name),function(x) x[x$Similarity==max(x$Similarity),])



   first        Name   Area Sample Similarity
   1   120   Pentanone 153744  PO2:1        981
   2   126 Methylamine  83528  PO4:1        887
   3   126   Sulfurous  43634  PO1:1        800
   4   126     Unknown  32741  PO2:1        645
   ```

Comment: +1 for the plyr approach and for seeing that `first` had to be included in there. I forgot that in my answer (now fixed) even though the result for this minimal example is the same.